# Getting data between 2 timestamps in MySQL with Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to get the data between two timestaamps in MySQL using Python3. There are no errors being thrown, however I am not getting data.

Here is the table setup:

```
cur.execute('''    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payroll ( 
        id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        employee_id INT,
        payment_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        payment VARCHAR(20)     
        ) 
    ''')
```

Here is the function that queries the database:

```
def get_payroll_payments_by_date(start, end):
    c = create_connection()
    cur = c[0]
    db = c[1]
    cur = db.cursor() 
    cur.execute("""
        select payment from payroll 
        where DATE(payment_date) between %s and %s
        order by payment_date desc;
        """, (start, end))    
    data = cur.fetchall()    
    return data

print(get_payroll_payments_by_date('08/01/2021', '08/01/2021'))
```

The query returns an empty list, even though there is data in the date range. I have looked at similar posts, but nothing that I have tried returns data. When I wake out the BETWEEN constraint I get the data.

Comment: your dates are formatting wrong; try '2021-08-01'.

Comment: note that your `DATE(payment_date) between` will not use an index on the date if there is one; better to do something like `payment_date between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-01 23:59:59'`

Comment: @ysth Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql. date forma is yyyy-mm-dd.

If you use that ypou don't need to convert the text like below

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payroll ( 
>         id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>         employee_id INT,
>         payment_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>         payment VARCHAR(20)     
>         )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO payroll VALUEs (NULL,1,NOW(), '1')
> ```

> ```
> select payment from payroll 
>         where payment_date between STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2021','%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2022','%d/%m/%Y')
>         order by payment_date desc;
> ```
>
> ```
> | payment |
> | :------ |
> | 1       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d638f9b72491be3f36fcef7c61185ee)*